# IPointerEnterHandler and IPointerExitHandler events with new input system

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

I'm trying to achieve a (I supposed) very simple behaviour, just a transition on mouse Enter/Exit on a UI element.

I'm currently using the new Input system and it seems that I'm getting strange behaviour.

I've correctly implemented the two interfaces `IPointerEnterHandler` and `IPointerExitHandler` but the methods are called only if the mouse button is pressed. So to trigger the 2 interfaces methods I have to keep mouse pressed... while I thought to see the events getting triggered just at mouse cursor over/exit.

What I'm doing wrong?